# Does mongodb PHP driver support ipv6?

Tags: php, mongodb, ipv6

Found this issue https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-219 but nobody even voted for it for almost 2 years.

Comment: Have you tried it? I mean maybe the driver accidently can accept ipv6 (not as crazy as it sounds) but that JIRA is right it isn't there yet...officially (if it does work for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

The PHP driver supports IPv6 fine, as long as you use a hostname in the connection string. The connection string parser currently doesn't understand IPv6 address notation yet, but that's tracked through https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-524

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about mongo native support, but from MySQL practices:

You would have to do some PHP cooking before putting IPv6 into DB:

Use 
 
    inet_pton() http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php 
and 
    inet_ntop() http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-ntop.php

And then store IP address as binary data.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking about the ability to connect to mongodb server using ipv6 address.